# Show how far two local branches have diverged

Tags: git

When my copy of master has diverged from origin/master and I invoke `git status`, the status output includes a summary like the following:

```
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 3 and 2 different commits each, respectively
```

How can I get this summary comparing two different local branches?

eg. For two branches, production and experimental:

```
'production' and 'experimental' have diverged,
and have 3 and 24 different commits each, respectively
```

---

The closest thing I've found so far (which is working well enough, I suppose, and could be scripted) is:

```
$ git rev-list production..experimental | wc -l
24
$ git rev-list experimental..production | wc -l
3
```

Comment: Ha! I was just about to post [that last edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25645309/2) as an answer! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered, `git rev-list` is the correct command.  You can simplify the counting of the selected revisions by adding `--count` to the `git rev-list` arguments.  The `A..B` and `B..A` style revision selectors are the correct ones, since they mean "the set of all commits reachable from the second revision, minus the set of all commits reachable from the first revision", which is what you want (and what `git status` uses as well, for that matter).